# searchable plugin ignores objects id

Tags: grails, lucene

I am using 0.5.5.1 grails searchable plugin. Search works on most of my objects and fields. However, I have a class with String id and it consists of a Number Dash Number like 1-1, 1-2, .. and so on. I cannot search this object by id. My guess its due to dash in it, it might be ignored by searchable analyzer? Not sure.. Any ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would first suggest that you download Luke http://code.google.com/p/luke/ and take a look at what exactly is going into the index.

The default index location is

```
"${user.home}/.grails/projects/${app.name}/searchable-index/${grails.env}"
```

it is quite possible that the dashes are getting removed when the index is being created based on the analyzer you are using to created the index.

I also believe you might need to do some character escaping when executing the query of the dash is included in the index

Comment: Thanks for your response. I downloaded luke and my index does show the id being indexed correctly with 1-1. I am trying escaping the -, does not seem to work for now... still testing

Comment: what does the query look like? what i usually do is get the query working in Luke first then go back to my code and correct the problem.

Comment: I suspect you are using the StandardAnalyzer, if you use the WhitespaceAnalyzer and create your query like this

stop\-gap

with the backslash, it will stay in the query

Comment: Running query in Luke directly for: 1-1 using: org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer or org.apache.lucene.analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer returns results but not with org.apache.lucene.analysis.SimpleAnalyzer... Weird because I believe by default Grails plugin is using Standard as well

Comment: you can change the analyzer in the configuration file Searchable.groovy

Comment: Tried that, I put:

compassSettings = [
'compass.engine.analyzer.whitespace.type': 'org.apache.lucene.analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer'
]

and searching with Parent.search(params.q,analyzer: 'whitespace')

still not returning the results for 1-1 while searching by other fields returns results

Comment: You have to put a "\" before the hypen in the query for it to work

Comment: I do but it still does not return the results, something is really off with my setup as I dont see my new entries being indexed. Only those that are there on start up...

Comment: Let's do one at a time,

Force a complete rebuild of your index to get the new index based on the new configuration.

Call indexAll action on searchableController then retry test

Comment: Run indexAll, results compass.CompassGpsUtils Finished Searchable Plugin bulk index, 884 ms. Running:
1. Location.search("1\\\\-1", analyzer: 'whitespace'), debug: search.DefaultSearchMethod query: [+1\-1 +(alias:Location)], [0] hits, took [1] millis
2. Location.search("1-1", analyzer: 'whitespace'), debug: search.DefaultSearchMethod query: [+1-1 +(alias:Location)], [0] hits, took [1] millis

Comment: Same 0 results with or without escape \

Comment: As a comparison, running: Location.search("motors", analyzer: 'whitespace'), debug: search.DefaultSearchMethod query: [+motors +(alias:Location)], [1] hits, took [0] millis

Comment: You are looking at Location.search, the \ there needs to be escaped, you will see that actual debug statement shows only one \ in +1\-1

Comment: Hmm getting somewhere, its only the ID field that is not being searched with a dash in it. If I put a dash in another field and search for it, I will get the results back.. This has to be something within the plugin...

Comment: i just re-read your question and I would suggest creating a field with a different name than "id" to solve you problem.

also...please accept the answer if you found it useful

Comment: Thank you for the time you spent going back and forth, it was very useful.